# updating published asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, publish

I just publish an `asp.net` website then i made changes in its source code i added two `.aspx` files and then publish it again

The question is what I need to make this changes take effect on server. Do I have to replace all files or i can just **add** specific file?

I'm trying to add two `aspx` pages to the site that already exist on the server 
and want to know which file i have to add beside the ordinary `aspx` file to take effect on site

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how you are deploying your code. Are you using the precompile option before publishing or just publishing with pre-compilation.

If you are just publishing then you can just replace the .aspx and aspx.cs files and the site will dynamically recompile.

If you have pre-compiled it then you are probably only left with .dll files and .aspx files so you would have to deploy a new copy of the .dll file for your site and the .aspx files. `MSDeploy` replaces the entire site by default.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only changed the aspx file and not the code behind it is enough to publish those two files and on the server. If you have changed the code behind as well you also need to publish the dll files, in that case it's probably easier to replace all of the files.